# FAILED: invokeApp org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A new session could not be created

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium-ios

```
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;

public class Demo {

AndroidDriver driver =null;
DesiredCapabilities capabilities;
File app = new File("/data/app/com.philips.sleepmapper.root-1/base.apk");

@Test
public void invokeApp() throws MalformedURLException
{
    capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("automationName", "Appium");
    capabilities.setCapability("paltformName", "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "6.0.1");
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceNmae", "Galaxy S6");

    capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());

    capabilities.setCapability("appPackage","com.philips.sleepmapper.root");
    capabilities.setCapability("appactivity","com.philips.sleepmapper.activity.SplashScreenActivity");

    driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

}
```

}

When executing this code i am getting the following error:

> FAILED: invokeApp org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: A
>   new session could not be created. (Original error: Bad app:
>   C:\data\app\com.philips.sleepmapper.root-1\base.apk. App paths need to
>   be absolute, or relative to the appium server.

Comment: Share your file structure Screenshot

Answer (score 2):

The path to your application APK is set incorrectly. I need to know your file structure to give the exact answer, but this is what I think is wrong.

Most likely you are trying to provide the application at `C:\path\to\my\project\data\app\com.philips.sleepmapper.root-1\base.apk`

If you run Appium in `C:\path\to\my\project` and you try to pass the relative path to the APK, you are missing the dot in the Appium test code. Change the path in the code to

`File app = new File("./data/app/com.philips.sleepmapper.root-1/base.apk");`

To make it work from any folder (absolute path) change the code to

`File app = new File("C:\path\to\my\project\data\app\com.philips.sleepmapper.root-1\base.apk");`

Remember to replace `path\to\my\project` with the real path you are using.

Comment: Hi mrtuovinen, Thanks for your suggestion, i have given .apk file path like this:  "File app = new File("C:\\Users\\310250972\\workspace\\DreamMapper_2.5_Alpha_July_5_65.apk");"  and the code get executed successfully. Do you have any idea how to automate listview elements in appium using slenenium (java)?

Comment: No problem. Please submit a new question about ListView elements.